# Kotlin property delegation not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, properties, getter, delegation

I'm confused about the different behaviour depending whether I use getters or delegated properties. Consider the following:

```
class Test {
    class Parts(val a: String, val b: String)

    var raw = ""
    private var cachedParts: Parts? = null

    val parts: Parts
        get() {
            println("@2")
            return cachedParts
                ?: raw.split("/")
                    .let { Parts(it.getOrElse(0) { "" }, it.getOrElse(1) { "" }) }
                    .also { cachedParts = it }
        }

    // WITH GETTERS:
    val partA get() = parts.a
    val partB get() = parts.b
}

fun main() {
    val t = Test()
    println("@1")
    
    t.raw = "one/two"

    println("a=${t.partA}, b=${t.partB}")
}
```

This code splits the string `raw` into two parts the first time `parts` is accessed. All later calls to `parts` will return the cached parts, even if `raw` changes. Output:

```
@1
@2
@2
a=one, b=two
```

The value of `raw` is empty when `Test` is created, but the accessors aren't called until we've set `raw` to some string. When `partA` and `partB` are finally accessed, they contain the correct value.

If I use property delegation instead, the code no longer works:

```
class Test {
    class Parts(val a: String, val b: String)

    var raw = ""
    private var cachedParts: Parts? = null

    val parts: Parts
        get() {
            println("@2")
            return cachedParts
                ?: raw.split("/")
                    .let { Parts(it.getOrElse(0) { "" }, it.getOrElse(1) { "" }) }
                    .also { cachedParts = it }
        }

    // WITH DELEGATION:
    val partA by parts::a
    val partB by parts::b
}

fun main() {
    val t = Test()
    println("@1")
    
    t.raw = "one/two"

    println("a=${t.partA}, b=${t.partB}")
}
```

All I've changed here is that `partA` is now delegated to `parts::a`, and the same for `partB`. For some strange reason, `partA` and `partB` are now accessed *before* the value of `raw` is set, so `cachedParts` is initilized with two empty parts. Output:

```
@2
@2
@1
a=, b=
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what your delegated properties translate to in the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#translation-rules-for-delegated-properties). For example, `partA` translates to:

```
private val partADelegate = parts::a
val partA: String
    get() = partADelegate.getValue(this, this::partA)
```

Notice that the callable reference expression `part::a` is used to initialise `partADelegate`. This expression is evaluated when the instance of `Test` is created, before `println("@1")`.

To evaluate `parts::a`, `parts` must be first evaluated. After all, this is a reference to the `a` property of `parts`, not a reference to `parts`.

Therefore, `parts` ends up being evaluated before `raw` gets its value.